# How to retain the border of selected bootstrap cards even on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having 6 bootstrap cards now I wrote code for storing the every card details in the local storage and also on click the card will get a border now I want is on page refresh I should retain the border of the card 
My html code is:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(1)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_1" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_1"><b>I am redecorating</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(2)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_2" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_2"><b>I am Moving</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(3)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_3" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_3"><b>I need help with a layout</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(4)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_4" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_4"><b>I am looking for a species</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(5)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_5" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_5"><b>I am moving with someone</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4" onclick="getGoal(6)">
    <div class="card4 mt-3" id="room_6" style="width: 12rem; height:9rem;">
      <center>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text mt-4" id="cont_6"><b>Other</b></p>
        </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--Loop ends-->
<a class="link mt-3"><u>Dont see your room?</u></a>
<div class="row mb-3">
  <div class="col-4 mr-5">
    <a href="/modsy/rooms/" class="previous" onClick="history.go(-1);">&laquo; Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 ml-5">
    <a href="/modsy/furniture" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // goals
  $("#room_1").click(function(){
    $("#room_1").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_2").click(function(){
    $("#room_2").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_3").click(function(){
    $("#room_3").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_4").click(function(){
    $("#room_4").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_5").click(function(){
    $("#room_5").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_6").click(function(){
    $("#room_6").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_7").click(function(){
    $("#room_7").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_8").click(function(){
    $("#room_8").toggleClass("blue");
  });

  $("#room_9").click(function(){
    $("#room_9").toggleClass("blue");
  });

});

var goal = [];
var goalIds = [];

function getGoal(id) {
  if (goal.length > 0) {
    var data = {
      id: id,
      content: $("#cont_" + id).text()
    }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    var index = goal.indexOf(x)
    if (index == -1) {
      goal.push(x);
    } else {
      goal.splice(index, 1);
    }
  } else {
    var data = {
      id: id,
      content: $("#cont_" + id).text()
    }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data);
    goal.push(x);
  }
  localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goal));
  goalIds = goal.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
  console.log(goalIds);
  issample();
}

function issample() {
  $("#goal").val(goalIds);
  console.log(goalIds);
}

function initGoals() {
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal") || '[]');
  goalIds = storedNames.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
}
```

My codepen link is: https://codepen.io/lakshmi123__/pen/xxbzwNP

Comment: also, you could add  `$("#room_"+id).toggleClass("blue");` to `getGoal()`, and remove all af the ugly click functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function initGoals() {
  goal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal") || '[]');
  goalIds = goal.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
  goalIds.forEach(function(i){$("#room_"+i).addClass('blue');});
}
initGoals();
```

but event then, you are filling your `goalIds` variable right with that function,but you are forgetting to fill the `goal` variable too ;)

Comment: I already storing the card details on click in the local storage see my code now what should I do

Comment: I need the border to retain how can you help me @Neil

Comment: @sssss edited my answer, did not see the initgoal function beacause it wasn't even called

Comment: the problem is I want to select any no.of cards on my wish for example if I select 1,2 the border is there for 1,2 and again I had 3 and 4 and refresh the border is coming for only 3 and 4 but  I want it to get for 1,2,3,4 also how it can be achieved

Comment: @ neil did you understand my problem?

Comment: i undersand, that is why i pointed to you that you only set goaldIds, and not goal variable, wich is the cause of your last problem

Comment: Now what should I do @Neil I didnt get it

Comment: @sssss i edited my answer again, it should work this time

Comment: what you did can you explain @Neil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205860/discussion-between-neil-and-sssss).